# Where can I discuss Esperanto online?

Tags: culture, learning, websites

I live in an area of the US with few if any Esperanto speakers nearby. What websites can I go to to discuss the language online. For example, I would like to be able to show people things I have written or discuss things others have written.

Answer (score 6):

I highly recommend installing Telegram. There is a list of public groups and channels in Esperanto at [Telegramo.org](http://telegramo.org). The main “esperantujo” group, which can be used to discuss anything and everything, has over a thousand users and is very active. There are also plenty of more specific groups for a variety of different topics. If you are a beginner you might want to check out the Esperanto-English group where you could speak in a mix of English and Esperanto and ask questions.

Otherwise there is [/r/Esperanto](https://www.reddit.com/r/Esperanto/) on Reddit which is a good place for sharing links. You can also use the [forums on Duolingo](https://www.duolingo.com/topic/915) to discuss.

Comment: I'd add Twitter to this! #Esperanto on there is really active, and there's even more speakers that don't use the hashtag.

Answer (score 1):

[italki](https://www.italki.com/ref=3188762x) has a free feature where you can post samples of your writing in Esperanto and people can comment on them or mark them up with corrections. (Comments and corrections are tracked as different threads.) You can also correct other people's works and get feedback on your corrections.

If you are on Facebook, I would encourage you to join [Esperanto USA - Usono](https://www.facebook.com/groups/EoUSA/), a discussion group for American Esperanto speakers. (Not affiliated with the national Esperanto organization.)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of Esperanto Learning groups on facebook that are fairly active. Duolingo Esperanto Learners is the first that comes to mind.